# Buttons and Text not having color information on Zeplin

Tags: photoshop, adobe-illustrator, psd, zeplin

I am making UI designs in Illustrator and then exporting it into .psd file.
From Photoshop I am exporting it to Zeplin. But my Buttons and font don't come up with css information (I want color info to be specific).
I have tried making things compound path in Illustrator, but it's still not working.

Comment: Why do you have to add Photoshop to your workflow? I'm unfamiliar with the specifics of Zeplin… does it demand Photoshop?

Comment: yes, you get to upload a layered .psd file to Zeplin

Comment: My suspicion is that you need to be careful about your naming of the PS layers; however, without more accurate diagnostic information, no one can tell you much.